# How to use jQuery WYSIWYG HTML editor in ASP.net page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am working in a blog application , i want to integrate the HTML editor of jQuery in ASP.net application.Although i have much easier option of using ASP.net AJAX toolkit editor , but it is not lightweight, so i want to go with jQuery HTML editor.

Can you suggest some tutorial which helps to do so.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try CKEditor. It is best of the breed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this one http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/

A very good one :-bd

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this jQuery [editor](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have a look at [tinymce editor](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/)